# In AdS/CFT, are the CFT states defined only on the boundary, or is it only the boundary theory that matters?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, holographic-principle

To be more specific than the title allows:

Gauge/gravity duality says that gauge theories on the boundary of an asymptotically AdS space are dual to gravitational theories in the bulk. I know the very basics of this proposed duality. I am curious, however, about the following situation:

Suppose you have some space that is asymptotically AdS. The common picture of a cylinder suffices for visualization. Suppose we define a CFT on the entire space, i.e. both the bulk and the boundary. Now, I know that the boundary states are the relevant ones for defining the gravitational theory in the bulk. But does the CFT in the bulk come into play here at all? Put another way, does the correspondence only work if the CFT is *only* defined on the boundary, or is it only the boundary that matters. Can we even do this, or have I misunderstood something fundamental?